# Specific data from txt file using C

Tags: c, search, text

Hello i have a text file that contains cities, dates and temperature. How can i read    temperature from specific city and day?  For example if I search for Alingsås 2014-05-14 I need to get 13.81, 11.59 and 13.81. The part I am stuck with is after i have opened the file and put variables for the city and date.  Info is stored in the text file like this:

```
Alingsås;
2014-05-14;
13.81;
11.59;
13.81;
2014-05-15;
8.89;
7.99;
9.15;
2014-05-16;
6.2;
5.07;
6.58;
2014-05-17;
7.91;
5.55;
7.91;
2014-05-18;
7.76;
5.95;
7.76;
2014-05-19;
7.95;
6.91;
9.72;
2014-05-20;
18.45;
12.92;
18.45;
Arboka;
2014-05-14;
9.55;
4.53;
10.66;
2014-05-15;
6.33;
1.5;
9.37;
2014-05-16;
8.85;
3.4;
12.08;
2014-05-17;
14.01;
4.8;
15.4;
2014-05-18;
14.16;
6.35;
17.23;
2014-05-19;
21.39;
14.57;
21.39;
2014-05-20;
23.34;
14.82;
23.34;
```

My Code so far is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>




int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
  char c;

  // open file

  fp =fopen("C:\\Users\\Karl\\Desktop\\info.txt", "r");

  if (fp != NULL)
  {      char city[10] = "Ålingsås";

         int temp1;
     int temp2;

         int temp3;
         char date[13] = "2014-05-14";
```

Comment: Add your code, so we can see "The part I am stuck with".

Comment: please show that **you** have done so far. we do not do your homework. btw: whoever designed that data format should be ...

Comment: `for(num=0; fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin); num++) switch (num % 5) case 0: ... case 1: ... ...}`

Comment: Don't you mean `Arboga` instead of `Arboka`? :)

Comment: are you sure you want to do this in C, because there's a bunch of (scripting) languages that are better suited for this kind of thing. If you're learning C, then this is a decent exercise, but if you just want to get the job done quickly, consider using Perl or Python, heck even JavaScript or PHP would make life easier. Any language with IO and parsing capabilities built in will do

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make a structure that contains the name of the city, and a pointer to another structure which will be an "array" (dynamically allocated on the heap) and where each entry contains the data and the three temperatures.

Then read one line at a time from the file, trim the input (to remove the leading and trailing whitespace, if there is any) and create the above structure. If the current line starts with a digit it's a date and read three more lines for the temperature and fill in the structure. If the current line doesn't start with a digit then you have a new city, and you create a new city-structure.